# store data in db or in files? which one is faster?

Tags: php, caching

I'm developing a pagerank checker widget. and i want to cache ranks. because on every page send a request to google takes takes a lot of seconds.

the general question:
cache (store, save!) rank of each url (and get it afterward) in a database is faster and optimizer or in files? (1 file for all, or 1 file for each)

sorry for my terrible english

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Have a read through [this article](http://www.aosabook.org/en/graphite.html) by Chris Davis - particularly section 7.10. You should also have a think about the differences between [speed and scalability](http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php).

While, in theory, the file based approach (using the directory hierarchy for indexing and one URL per file) will be faster, PHP does not have good facilities for managing concurrent file access. OTOH this is a key feature of a DBMS (be it relational or nosql). Another consideration is how you will be *interacting* with the data - you may not be retrieving it using the same indexing path as you stored it in (you can still implement multiple indexes with files, but its a lot easier in a database).

Answer (score 1):

Go with the database, and remember to enable indexing for columns you care about.

Comment: Once the result is stored to database then what if data is changed on live? what should be the criteria to match result of live with your database??

Comment: Databases do cache some information in memory (tweakable with most databases, I imagine). But most importantly, they are typically built to handle queries. Built by people smarter than me. Which means when you query that database, it's going to return useful results a lot faster than a hacked searching method on a regular file. If you do a lot of queries, a DB is your best friend. If you are just doing linear reads or dealing with giant Blobs, forego the database and stick to regular files.

Comment: I agree with database operation as you said dear. But my question is about the synchronization of data? How you will synchronize the stored data with live?

Comment: By whatever method he is receiving the live data to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

How about using something like memcached which stores the data in memory?  If it's just cache, I don't see the downside.

Answer (score 0):

Using files will be slower than using database ...
As database uses several optimization's and best algorithms for storing and retrieving data , it is the best option to choose..
You can give indexing to your database and you can choose the database engine ( if using mysql ) as MEMORY (HEAP) Storage Engine for more faster performance..

Comment: Depends on what language you are writing to file with and how you do it.  Database are just files.

Comment: Once the result is stored to database then what if data is changed on live? what should be the criteria to match result of live with your database??

Comment: [You can refer the mysql website for more details ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

Answer (score 0):

Cache the result is more better. Use mamchached or something like similar. You just need to first check that whether you have chached data, if so then don't send request to API and take data from there. But set time for cache (after that the cache will be destroyed). This will help you to synchronize your data with live. IF you have not cached data, then send request to api and store the latest data to cache. Its better in my opinion.